# Do I need to install certificate into my server if i am not using DocuSign Embedded Signing?

Tags: ssl, docusignapi

[DocuSign documentation](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/API_Certification_Post_04_08_16.pdf) show that if using Embedded Signing or CONNECT, SSL need to implemented.

> **Security Certificates**
>
> 8. If your integration uses Embedded Signing and/or DocuSign Connect Service, you may have to implement your SSL or X509 Certificate.
>
>    - For Connect, please review our DocuSign Connect Service Guide, link provided below. You are required to provide a secure listener or an x509 Certificate.
>    - If you use an x509 Certificate for Embedded Signing, please send your Account Manager the x509 Certificate’s Common Name, Issuer’s Name, Version, Serial Number, and Valid From and Valid To dates.

Does it mean that If i am not using the Embedded Signing or CONNECT then do I need to put the DocuSign root certificate into my server?  I am just using the  [DocuSign Java Api](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client) that downloaded from Git.

If not which one to add? there are alot of certificates they have provided in this link [DocuSign Trust](https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/docusign-public-certificates/)

Answer (score 2):

Docusign Connect sends HTTP POST messages to the endpoint you specify (i.e., to an endpoint on your server).

- In the DocuSign **demo environment** (i.e., using your developer sandbox account), DocuSign Connect will send messages to either an **HTTP or HTTPS** endpoint.
- However, in the DocuSign **production environment** (i.e., using a docusign.net account), DocuSign Connect requires that your endpoint be **HTTPS**. So when you're ready for your integration to 'go live' in the production environment, you'll need to ensure that the endpoint you've specified for Connect to send messages to is HTTPS (and if necessary, implement SSL to enable HTTPS for that endpoint).

Answer (score 1):

Given what you said, and as long as you can make API calls (via HTTPS) without issue, then I would say you have no need to install any DocuSign certs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that section of the document is out of date. Embedded signing does not require a customer to trust a DocuSign certificate.

I will work to get it updated.